# If the group value contains value replace with new value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

input DF

```
Date                  event   type
2023-04-11 13:42:16   play     a
2023-04-11 14:02:26   play     x
2023-04-11 14:36:09   play     a
2023-04-11 14:37:46   start    x
2023-04-11 14:41:34   start    y
2023-04-11 14:46:27   start    x
2023-04-11 14:47:03   start    x
```

desired output

```
Date                  event   type
2023-04-11 13:42:16   play     **x**
2023-04-11 14:02:26   play     x
2023-04-11 14:36:09   play     **x**
2023-04-11 14:37:46   start    x
2023-04-11 14:41:34   start    y
2023-04-11 14:46:27   start    x
2023-04-11 14:47:03   start    x
```

if type contains 'a' group by event then replace 'x'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
is_a_in_group = df.groupby('event').type.transform(lambda x: (x == 'a').any())
df.loc[is_a_in_group & (df.type == 'a'), 'type'] = 'x'
```

`is_a_in_group` will return boolean series where it will return True when there is at least 1 "a" in a same event and False if there is no "a".

And use the condition along with when `type == "a"`, if both are True, then assign "x".

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need:

```
d = dict(zip(df["type"], df["type"]))
d.update({"a": "x"})
df["type"] = df.groupby("event", as_index=False)["type"].transform(lambda x: x.map(d))
print(df)

                  Date  event type
0  2023-04-11 13:42:16   play    x
1  2023-04-11 14:02:26   play    x
2  2023-04-11 14:36:09   play    x
3  2023-04-11 14:37:46  start    x
4  2023-04-11 14:41:34  start    y
5  2023-04-11 14:46:27  start    x
6  2023-04-11 14:47:03  start    x
```

Answer (score 0):

use `groupby` with `transform` without lambda:

```
df.loc[(df['type'] == 'a').groupby(df['event']).transform('any'), 'type'] = 'x'
df
                  Date  event type
0  2023-04-11 13:42:16   play    x
1  2023-04-11 14:02:26   play    x
2  2023-04-11 14:36:09   play    x
3  2023-04-11 14:37:46  start    x
4  2023-04-11 14:41:34  start    y
5  2023-04-11 14:46:27  start    x
6  2023-04-11 14:47:03  start    x
```

The 'type' column is updated in-place.